# Errors with routing links angular 4 on GoDaddy

Tags: angular, routes

I'm having a problem with my website. It's written in Angular 4.

Here's the problem: I can only use the link: www.mywebsite.com
if I use for example: www.mywebsite.com/page , www.mywebsite.com/page1
It will give me an error. It's mean, if I first go to mywebsite.com then click on the links, then it displays the pages correct. But, if I'll put in the browser mywebsite.com/page then it will give me error page.

I'm using the standard angular router and host it on GoDaddy. Any idea why is it happening?

Answer (score 7):

Ok, I've found a solution - here:
https://www.godaddy.com/community/VPS-Dedicated-Servers/Using-Angular-2-routing-on-Linux-Hosting-with-cPanel/m-p/33959#M1119

In short, you need to add to the .htaccess file this code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /myappdirectory/
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Where myappdirectory is the main directory on your hosting service that the app is there